# bypass traffic on Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, vpn, proxy

I have two VMs(Ubuntu 20):

1. `vm-1`
2. `vm-2`

I want to bypass all traffic of `vm-1` to `vm-2` and run `vpn` on `vm-1` to when I connect to `vm-1`
by `vpn` send all traffic to `vm-2`.
If I want to explain more imagine that `vm-1` has restricted access to some social networks like Instagram, Whats app and Telegram and I want to bypass this limitation.
So thank you very much if you have a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need VPN for this, you can use an `ssh` tunnel.

From `vm-with-restricted-internet` run:

```
ssh -D 9090 -N -f user@vm-with-free-internet
```

Then you can tell your Applications on `vm-with-restricted-internet` to use a Socks proxy on `localhost:9090`.

E.g. Firefox -> Settings -> General -> Network Settings -> Socks Proxy.

or for Terminal applications:

```bash
export ALL_PROXY="socks5h://localhost:9090"
```

Comment: If I want to explain more the vm-1 and my local pc are in region that social medias restricted and vm-2 is in free internet region.
so why run ssh tunnel in vm-2 ?

Comment: okay, I misunderstood then your question, I thought it was vice versa. Then it's simply the other way. I fixed to make it clear.

Comment: thank you so mush. Its working now.
do you know any applications for ios to send all data to proxy server?

Comment: oh sorry, no idea about ios.